# Spark Dataframe comparison in Unit testing to check the Functionality

Tags: scala, dataframe, unit-testing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created few methods that will transform dataframes into required format and to filter multiple error checks and to update the dataframe based on error rules.

I am new to write unit testing in scala on intelliJ.
I have to write unit testing to compare the actual dataframes with expected result.

Below is the unit test case i wrote for pivot functionality of the dataframe. Similar way i have to compare the obtained datasets with expected dataframe.

```
 @Test
  def testPivotingDataFramePositive(): Unit = {

    val inputDf = spark.read.option("header",true).csv("src/test/resources/input-test-files/pivotInput.csv")
    val expectedResult = spark.read.option("header",true).csv("src/test/resources/output-test-files/pivotOutput.csv")
    val actualResult = parserObj.pivotingDataFrame(inputDf)
    assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult)
}
```

Even the above test case is failing by throwing differences, even though both dataframes are same (might be because of the dataframe records ordering at each time).

Even tried the below comparison and it failed by giving output as 0 even though the dataframes are same.

```
assert (actualResult.except(expectedResult).count() != 0 && expectedResult.except(actualResult).count != 0)
```

How could i test the dataframe transform functionality effectively in unit testing?

Answer (score 2):

Better to use library  `"com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "3.0.0_1.0.0" % "test"` Instead of writing own functions to validate dataframe.

It is very efficient to test RDD, Dataframe and structured Streaming.

Github URL:
https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base

```
  class test extends FunSuite with DataFrameSuiteBase {
  test("DataFrame test") {
    val sqlCtx = sqlContext
    import sqlCtx.implicits._

    val input1 = sc.parallelize(List[(Int, Double)]((1, 1.1), (2, 2.2), (3, 3.3))).toDF
    val input2 = sc.parallelize(List[(Int, Double)]((1, 1.2), (2, 2.3), (3, 3.4))).toDF
    assertDataFrameApproximateEquals(input1, input2, 0.11) // equal

    intercept[org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException] {
      assertDataFrameApproximateEquals(input1, input2, 0.05) // not equal
    }
  }
}
```

Here is wiki: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki